# How do I convert a polysurface to a mesh in Rhino3d

Tags: mesh, rhino, rhino3d

I extruded a curve then caped it and converted to a poly-surface. now I want to convert to a mesh, how doI about doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the polysurface and then run the Mesh command: Mesh->From NURBS Object on the menu.

By the way, this isn't really a programming question, so it's not really appropriate for StackOverflow. However, we'd love to have you ask Rhino related questions at http://discourse.mcneel.com/